# Pass in Camunda execution environment to Java Delegate Expression?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to use a Java Delegate Expression (Similar to TaskListener's Expression where you can pass a TaskDelegate to the expression context).
In a nutshell - am trying to accomplish what taskListener allows to pass in a `TaskDelegate` using the expression `${myDelegate.doSomething(task)}` which works fine for TaskListener!

However Im trying to do the same using the Delegate's expression. I understand we can do this which works `${myDelegate.doSomething()}` (without any Runtime Engine's params) but I need the Runtime from which we can get the ProcessRuntimeExecution etc! I don't want to use the Java  Delegate's `execute` method since I am reusing this Delegate for a User Task's TaskListener methods.

`${myDelegate.doSomething(WHAT DO I PASS HERE TO GET Camunda Runtime?)}`

```
public class MyDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
    public void doSomething( CAMUNDA RUNTIME? ) {
        // Get the ProcessEngine etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [DelegateExcecution](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.13/org/camunda/bpm/engine/delegate/DelegateExecution.html).